# Android Toast-like dialog across multiple activities

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, popupwindow

My app returns a collection of status messages which I'm currently displaying in Toast dialogs.  However, the number of status messages is steadily increasing which makes Toast a less viable option.

What I want to do is create a dialog that displays messages in a ListView.  However, any dialog I create is shown on top of an activity and so when I change activities the dialog is lost.  How can I create a dialog that maintains its visibility across activities, like Toast does?

Comment: How can you change the activity,when Dialog is visible?

Comment: Because the dialog just shows what's going on in a background thread.  The user might change activities before the background thread returns.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are looking for some kind of notification service that already exists in Android. You can solve this on different levels:

In App

- for Example create a BaseActivity that always has some sort of list that contains the messages you want the user to see, and extend for the activities you want. And keep some kind of a Queue for unread messages. How you visualize this is completely up to you.

Use the systems notification and consider Updating notifications.

- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Comment: Not really after notifications, but the first idea sounds interesting and possible.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Dave did the first idea work out for you? Or anything else you were able to figure out? I am looking for exactly same thing. Thanks

Comment: I think I ended up storing the list of message independently of the activity and then in all of my activities I displayed the messages if there were any.